Transfer repositories between orgs using a Github App (and only its access token)
Context:
I have a Github App that centralizes a bunch of Github services for my clients. One of them is transfer a repository between orgs (same enterprise).
It requires my client's access token, but if he doesn't have owner permission on both orgs, I can't transfer de repo.
What i'm doing:
Currently the bot:

Makes a POST to https://github.com/login/device/code with the clientId as a parameter.
Receive the  user_code and device_code
Asks my client to manually go to https://github.com/login/device , type the user_code and authorize the App to transfer
Polls https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token waiting for the user authorization
Transfer the repository

Ref 01
Ref 02
Ref 03 (step 5 for the polling)

Problem
It works great when my client is owner of both orgs. But that's not most cases.
I'd like to transfer a repo between orgs even if my client isn't owner of any of the orgs.
What I'd like to do
My App have write permission on all orgs. Can't I use its token to transfer a repo? If so, how can I get only one token to "control" all orgs at the same time?
Currently I'm getting the App's token by making a POST here https://api.github.com/app/installations/${installationId}/access_tokens , what gives me one token per ORG, which does not help me on transferring a repo between orgs.
